# Find the name of the caller in hyperledger

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

How would I find the name of the user invoking chaincode in hyperledger?

in v0.5 this information was included in the transaction certificate however in v0.6 the 'common name' attribute has been changed to just say "Transaction Certificate" - the name has been removed.

Comment: kind have a look, https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/pull/2001

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how I can find the name of a user from this? - it just seems to say that it's been removed...

(sorry if I'm missing something obvious)

Comment: kindly read the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

This is totally intentional to exclude `enrollID` from the subject of transaction certificate this is because `tcerts` are used for **unlinkability**.

You can read [this](https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/1409) for more information.